# Room/SQLite Static Value for Alias

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I’m looking to do something like the following where the department column doesn’t exist (this is just an example):

```
SELECT name, 'IT' as department FROM employees_table

name       department
---------- ----------
John       IT
Mike       IT
Sally      IT
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
error: no viable alternative at input
```

I understand this works in other databases, but, apparently, not Room/SQLite.  Would someone please hit me with a clue stick and help me achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine in sqlite. You should include how you're trying to execute this query. The error is probably related to that and not the database.

Comment: Thank you for chiming in Shawn.  While I’ve already been taking a long hard look at this, you forced me to look even harder and I uncovered this as a reserved keyword issue with my column name in my actual SQL.  I’ll post an answer to this question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my column name is a SQLite keyword.  Doh!

The actual code looked something more like:

```
SELECT name, 'Running' as action FROM example_table
```

Changing this to the following resolved the issue:

```
SELECT name, 'Running' as 'action' FROM example_table
```